# make document.getElementById into a var

Tags: getelementbyid, var

Is there any way you can make "document.getElementById" into a variable?

I want to be able to write

myVariable("id").innerHTML = (blabla);

instead of

document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = (blabla);

Pardon me if this has been answered. I've sought and found nil! *newbie*

Comment: try using jquery which makes it relatively easy

Comment: you create js function to return object by ID

Comment: Thanks for your answers! However, I cannot use jquery, just javascript (school assignment). I am not sure how to create the function...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a simpler way to call common code, you can just define your own function like **migvill** suggests.

To answer the question directly though, you *can* point to the `document.getElementById` function (or any other function) using a variable. This is as obvious as you could imagine:

```
var myVariable = document.getElementById;
```

The problem with this is that the function itself (the object that `myVariable` now points to) is not intrinsically linked to the `document` object that it is designed to work with. When you write `document.getElementById("id")`, the `document` is automatically given to the function, but with `myVariable` you would need to specify it. This can be done using the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) function:

```
myVariable.call(document, "id").innerHTML = "blabla";
```

And finally, the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function can be used to create a *new* function that automatically links the given object (this has essentially the same effect as defining your own wrapper function):

```
var newFunc = myVariable.bind(document);

newFunc("id").innerHTML = "blabla";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for increasing my limited knowledge of Javascript. Checking other peoples code and forums like this is how I learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the output into another function

```
var shortID = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
shortID('myID').innerHTML = "...";
```

Comment: Works great! It was so simple I didn't know I actually knew the answer. *many thanks migvill!*